Разбить строчку через регулярное выражение
/test-user

Как правильно разбить строчку через
preg_split

При условии что за место test и user могут быть другие значения и получить на выходе массив с двумя значениями test и user

У меня получилось разбить строку регулярным выражением, достав оттуда только строки, с помощью preg_split следующим образом:
$text = '/test-user';
$res = preg_split('/\W/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($res);

Результат:
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => user
)


А зачем тут preg_split?
$val = '/test-user';
$result = explode('-', trim($val, '/'));  
// Или другой вариант, записывающий значения в отдельные переменные
[$firstVal, $secondVal] = explode('-', trim($val, '/'));

